Firefox won't launch with imported profile
I've had this problem before, not sure what fixed it last time, but I'm having it again. I have a root profile folder from my Firefox Nightly backed up. So on a new machine I install Nightly, create new profile, put inside the contents of my backup, launch it again and it just works. Repeat the steps with Dev edition and it just refuses to launch with newly imported profile.

Only time I had such an issue was moving a profile from Windows to Linux or vice versa, though you don't mention that is the case. (Likely it was the EOL convention causing the issue.)

Ok, I think I figured it out. I've had this problem on macOS, since I only use a single install on Windows. So I installed Dev there as well, and it didn't work, BUT, unlike macOS it gave me an error that clearly said it didn't like that my profile is from newer FF version than the one that I'm running (makes sense since Nightly is a bit ahead of Dev). I found a year old backup of my Nightly profile and Dev version now works with it just fine.

This answer would be helpful if formatted to make it readable.
